# What is the clock rate of my chip processor?

Tags: intel

My "My PC" displays that my processor is "i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80 GHz 1.99 GHz". I wonder which is my intel chip clock rate, 1.8 or 1.99?

Comment: Check this out https://ark.intel.com/products/122589/Intel-Core-i7-8550U-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_00-GHz

Comment: This is under Windows, right?  Is the `1.99GHz` on a separate line, so it looks like a separate piece of information?

Answer (score 3):

1.99GHz is probably the current frequency, while 1.80GHz is the "sticker frequency", the rated sustained frequency under all workload / temperature conditions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost.

It's an i7, so it does support Turbo.

Comment: Its max turbo frequency is 4 GHz

Comment: @Srikanth: then it's not running at *max* turbo, if my interpretation is correct.  That's normal; the operating point for a CPU-intensive workload can easily be just a bit higher than the sticker frequency, if it's something like Prime95 or a game.  The sticker frequency is very low on the low-power U-series CPUs, so often they can turbo a lot higher, but sustained high-power-draw workloads will reduce the CPU frequency.  So will workloads that make heat from the GPU.